# Python time conversion

Tags: python, django

I  have some timestamp data from a database and I need to convert it to a Python `datetime` (in `tuple` format). How can  I do that?

For instance, I need to convert *2013-04-16 16:31:35.649+05:30* format to *datetime(2013, 4, 16, 16, 31, 35)*.

I am trying to do the, Django, new user registration part of the project and whenever the user submits the data and registers then he gets an verification email but whenever the user clicks the verification link then, it produces the following error:

> can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware `datetimes`

Comment: How are you selecting it from the database? It looks like you're trying to convert a timestamp to a datetime... What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `"2013-04-16 16:31:35.649+05:30"` is the data stored in database ? I don't think storing the offset `+5:30` would prove useful, or simplify anything.

Comment: i am using postgresql database..

Answer (score 3):

```
from dateutil import parser

dt = parser.parse("2013-04-16 16:31:35.649+05:30")
# dt == datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 16, 16, 31, 35, 649000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))

dt.astimezone(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)
```

returns `datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 16, 11, 1, 35, 649000)` which is the same instant in UTC and without tzinfo (offset-naive).

If you want to store datetime objects without tzinfo, then store it in UTC.

Large parts of the world use daylight saving time, which makes some offset-naive datetimes ambiguous. UTC does not have these problems.